# initWithData:encoding always return null

Tags: objective-c, encoding, decode

I am working on an iphone application which need to encode and decode a string,so I code a small script on obj-c to test my code. This is my code which I am using to test:

this code block is not work, the string AwEMT... is a encoded string by dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding and base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0, just like the working code block but when i decode it is not work and return null

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    NSData *decodedData1 = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:@"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" options:0];
    NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", decodedData1 );


    return 0;
    }
```

And this is working code block, I encode the "Developer" string the same way as encoded string: "AwEMT.... But the encoded string from "Developer" can eassily decode by these code.

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

        NSString *myString = @"Developer";
        NSData *myData = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *base64String = [myData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
        NSLog(@"%@", base64String);

        NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:0];
        NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", decodedString);

                return 0;
        }
```

Anyone know what I have done wrong on this? please point me out

Comment: Probably there is a problem with the base64 string. Where are you getting it from? Is encryption involved?

Comment: I tested your base64 encoded string on https://codebeautify.org/base64-decode and the result is weird. Is your string really in `NSUTF8StringEncoding`? It's unclear if `decodedData1` is nil. If not, your base64 string is valid, but it may not be valid in UTF8. Maybe ASCII?

Comment: @Larme I have tried to debug decodedData1 and it is not nil, so i can make sure that the base64 string is valid because the code can decode it to NSData. But when i tried to decode the NsData to string it is nil right there

Comment: I'd say it's because of the encoding. What is supposed to be the value of that? What's the use?

Comment: @Larme The orgin value of encoded string is a json with config value for my application! Btw, i have tried to use ASCII but it just return a string that look like chinese or something like that, cant read it and is not the orign value of the string

Comment: Your string doesn't look at all like JSON. It's maybe encrypted, or not correctly saved. It has issue that's sure.

Comment: I can make sure that the string is in Json but I really dont know why it cant decode like this @@

Comment: Show how you did retrieve it.

Comment: I can not provide the way encoded it because I don't have the permission to share it. But I just recieve an info that it is encoded with salt bro

Comment: @duongkhang, ok, so encryption is involved. I am almost sure the string is not UTF8, you need to figure out which encoding it is, and then when you get a non nil string, decrypt it.

Comment: @pckill I have firgure out that it is encoded by ASCII encoding :). but still can't decrypt it